# Laravel - Three stages of for loops - Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, web

I have three models and have to follow the hierarchy (Module > Chapter > Lesson)

I'm trying to make a loop that will get all from the database and print out accordingly

```
@foreach($modules as $module)
<h4>{{ $module->title }}</h4>
<div id="chapter_bar" style="padding-left: 30px;">
    @foreach($module->chapters as $chapter)
    <h5>{{ $chapter->title }}</h5>
    <ul>
        @foreach($chapter->lessons as $lesson)
        <li>{{ $lesson->title }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endforeach
```

Everything works fine until the lessons are printed out, since in each module chapters' ids reset from 1. Chapters are printed in the correct module, but their lessons are not.

[Modules > Chapters > Lessons List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSVTF.png)

[Data Structure in DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxPGF.png)

Model relationships:

Module

```
public function chapters(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Chapter');
}

public function lessons(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Lesson');
}
```

Chapter

```
public function lessons(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Lesson');
}

public function module(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Module');
}
```

Lesson

```
public function chapter(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Chapter');
}

public function module(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Module');
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your data's structure?

Comment: Are you sure that the titles within your model are correct? The numbers do not come from HTML....

Comment: The logic is sound.  It looks like the data is incorrect.

Comment: The [Laravel documentation for Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) might be of use to you. It shows you how to define relationships within the ORM and also retrieve related records. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I've added data structure example

Comment: Add your model definitions... there is something wrong with your relationships...

Comment: Added model relationships..

Comment: Why do you have `l1,l2,l1,l2` in the list? Do you have repeated lectures in same chapter ?! Given db screenshot doesn't seem to have repetition though!!

Comment: Hi Leninhasda, I've only updated it to be more readable. Updated the image

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding when you are doing `$chapter->lessons` it's returning all the lessons (with id: 1,2,4,5) from the db. It's because the relation you set in the chapter model:

```
// Chapter model
public function lessons(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Lesson');
}
```

Which is only checking the relation between chapter id and lesson id. But you need the module id checking as well.

I don't know any better way to do this but you can do something like following to add the module id filter:

```
// Chapter model
public function lessons(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Lesson')->where('module_id', $this->module_id)->all();
}
```

aka: give me all the lessons of this chapter where their module id is same as the chapter's module id.
I hope you get the point. Hope this helps or at least give you some idea!